# How to use DBI::dbConnect() to read and write tables from multiple databases

Tags: r, database, dbi, dbplyr

I have a Netezza SQL server I connect to using DBI::dbConnect.  The server has multiple databases we will name db1 and db2.

I would like to use dbplyr as much as possible and skip having to write SQL code in RODBC::sqlQuery(), but I am not sure how to do the following:.

1) How to read a table in db1, work on it and have the server write the result into a table in db2 without going through my desktop?
2) How to do a left join between a table in db1 and another in db2 ?

It looks like there might be a way to connect to database ="SYSTEM" instead of database = "db1" or "db2", but I am not sure what a next step would be.

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
             driver = "NetezzaSQL",
             database = "SYSTEM",
             uid = Sys.getenv("netezza_username"),
             pwd = Sys.getenv("netezza_password"),
             server = "NETEZZA_SERVER",
             port = 5480)
```

Comment: (1) You can typically track multiple separate connections simultaneously, as in `con1 <- DBI::dbConnect(...); con2 <- DBI::dbConnect(...)`, though it's over to you to manage which connection to use. Some DBMS's allow you to change the database via SQL itself, though many do not (e.g., mssql). (2) The only way to join *in database* from two different databases is if at least one of them supports foreign data wrappers and/or foreign tables, and that has nothing to do with R (and is very non-trivial). Lacking that, download both into R and then join ... probably not what you want/need.

Comment: Thanks r2evans. I know how to create two connections, read from one to my desktop , work on my desktop and write to the other, but I was really hoping for something that would not need to go through my desktop - thanks for warning me that this is not trivial ! :)

Comment: I think you need a database link established on your database first. Then it's just a connection to one of the db and some SQL.  https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-create-database-link/

Comment: https://dwgeek.com/netezza-cross-database-access-restrictions.html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work around this problem on SQL server using `in_schema` and `dbExecute` as follows. Assuming Netezza is not too different.

#### Part 1: shared connection

The first problem is to connect to both tables via the same connection. If we use a different connection then joining the two tables results in data being copied from one connection to the other which is very slow.

```r
con <- dbConnect(...) # as required by your database

table_1 <- dplyr::tbl(con, from = dbplyr::in_schema("db1", "table_name_1"))
table_2 <- dplyr::tbl(con, from = dbplyr::in_schema("db2.schema2", "table_name_2"))
```

While `in_schema` is intended for passing  schema names you can also use it for passing the database name (or both with a dot in between).

The following should now work without issue:

```r
# check connection
head(table_1)
head(table_2)

# test join code
left_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id") %>% show_query()
# check left join
left_join(table_1, table_2, by = "id") %>% head()
```

#### Part 2: write to datebase

A remote table is defined by two things

1. The connection
2. The code of the current query (e.g. the result of `show_query`)

We can use these with `dbExecute` to write to the database. My example will be with SQL server (which uses `INTO` as the keyword, you'll have to adapt to your own environment if the sql syntax is different).

```r
# optional, extract connection from table-to-save
con <- table_to_save$src$con

# SQL query
sql_query <- paste0("SELECT *\n",
                    "INTO db1.new_table \n", # the database and name you want to save
                    "FROM (\n",
                    dbplyr::sql_render(table_to_save),
                    "\n) subquery_alias")
# run query
dbExecute(con, as.character(sql_query))
```

The idea is to create a query that can be executed by the database that will write the new table. I have done this by treating the existing query as a subquery of the `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM (...) subquery_alias` pattern.

#### Notes:

- If the sql query produced by `show_query` or `sql_render` would work when you access the database directly then the above should work (all that changes is the command is arriving via R instead of via the sql console).
- The functions I have written to smooth this process for me can be found on [here](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers). They also include appending, deleting, compressing, indexing, and handling views.
- Writing a table via `dbExecute` will error if the table already exists in the database, so I recommend checking for this first.
- I use this work around in other places, but inserting the database name with `in_schema` has not worked for creating views. To create (or delete) a view I have to ensure the connection is to the database where I want the view.

Comment: Thanks for the write up!
Reading up on terminology here (https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/schema/) and looking at the collection pane here (https://db.rstudio.com/rstudio/connections/), I believe your solution works when both tables are on the same databases, but in a different schema.

My problem is that my tables are in a different *database*, but on the same server.  Should it still work?

Comment: connecting to a database, then querying the second does work:

db1_con<- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
 driver = "NetezzaSQL",
 database = "db1",
 uid = "user"),
 pwd = "pwd),
 server = "server",
port = 5480)

table_2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(db1_con, 'SELECT * 
  FROM db2..table2')

Comment: A key point of my answer is that `in_schema` can be used to provide the database name. This works because R would put a schema name before the table table (schema.table) which is the same thing you want it to do with a database name (db.table).